# How can I do a difference between values at t0 and t1 in a received data set in Grafana?

Tags: snmp, grafana, fortinet, telegraf, snmpv3

I am trying capture the interface bandwidth on a firewall using SNMPv3 and show it on Grafana, I want to do a difference in values at t0 and t1 in the table below in Grafana, for eg., for a difference between the first and second value in snmp.distinct (which is the inoctet received via SNMPv3 OID) column or Time-0 column below,
[image]

Comment: I guess I need to use the Transform feature, but not sure what options within those will work or if there is a better way to do it